# VScode live share running on the same terminal

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

We are making a web app, and using Vscode live share feature, to edit on the same code. Altough we can edit the same code, my colleague cannot run the html code(chrome) in his own computer, for some reason we are on the same terminal(my mac), and when he runs it we see an error on my side too. How can we solve this issue on my end, to I have to give permissions? And how do we create a a different terminal for him using the base code.

Comment: You probably want to share the server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/use/vscode#share-a-server (or run something like [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve), [nginx](https://www.nginx.com), [apache](https://projects.apache.org/project.html?httpd-http_server) or similar to serve the files and share that server)

Comment: So we can now run the web app, but the problem is that it is still launched on my mac, instead of his, can this be solved changing the launch.json file configs? I try to add a server from my mac, but it gives me error. He also cannot npm run it through the terminal

Comment: There isn't much you can do, since (as far as I am aware) the files are not saved to his computer. What you could do is share a different server via Remotes, though that eliminates co-editing.